# MAC address of source and destination field in a packet

Tags: networking

I was always curious about the following:

suppose that there is a PC connected to the Switch A which is again connected to the Router B. This router is again connected to the Router C. Now, the Router C is connected to the Switch D, which is connected to the Server E.

So, if the PC sends a packet that has destination as Server E, what will be the MAC address area of the destination and source field in the packet?

Answer (score 1):

Source will be the MAC address of the *outgoing* network card as determined via the routing table on the PC. Destination will be the MAC address of the switch-A-facing network card on the router B, determined again via the routing table on the PC and the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) results.